# C++. OpenCV. Count number of conturs

Tags: c++, opencv

I need get number of contours (only closed/looped contours) from my image. For this purpose I use `cv::connectedComponents` function. As it said in documentation

> returns N, the total number of labels [0, N-1] where 0 represents the background label

So to get real nubmer of counturs I just need decrement returned value (sub background contour). This method works fine for most images I need to process (actually, it autocad files). However, I've got one image which is processed incorrectly. Returned value for this image 4, however we see that there are 4 circles on image and background. So returned value should be 5.
Here is image I got the problem with:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
void run_test()
{
    cv::Mat img, img_edge, labels;

    img = cv::imread("G:\\test.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::threshold(img, img_edge, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    int res = cv::connectedComponents(img_edge, labels, 8, CV_16U);
}
```

So I've got two questions: why returned value for this image is 4(but not 5) and is it correct way (by using `connectedComponents`) to get number of contours?

Comment: The bottom right small circle seems connected to the large circle (two pixels of each have an adjacent corner ). Its label is probably the same as the large circle

Comment: are there any other ways to find the number of contours?

Comment: have you tried actually finding circles instead of contours? are the circles always of the same size?

Comment: It really depends why *you* considers the contour should be different. Actually, the *fact* is that both circles **are** adjacent (with 8-connectivity). Thus why do you consider they are not the same? Once you have a clear answer to this question, you can think to implement it.

Comment: @api55, algorithm should be common because it is used for large amount of AutoCAD drawings. So I can't search only for circles.

Comment: Does using 4-connectivity instead of 8 possible for you, without breaking other cases?

Comment: @unlut, no. When I user 4 instead of 8 it returns 49 contours